# Is there any program that would allow me to skin a specific app without changing that app's code?

Tags: windows

I'm just interested to see if there's any way of doing this, specifically for discord. Yes, I know discord doesn't care if you use a modified version - I'm just curious if you could use a theme without breaking their tos at all

Answer (score 0):

No. If an app doesn't support theming itself, there almost definitely won't be a custom app providing theming option for it. As a web app it definitely has theming options though, at least the browser version. There are various extensions that let you modify CSS of websites, like [Stylus](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne) or [Stylish](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?pli=1). The desktop one might be packaged in a way that doesn't let you modify CSS

But your best bet is, as you mentioned, using something like [BetterDiscord](https://betterdiscord.app/themes) that supports theming.